# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.component.html.HtmlAjaxSupport

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x

We are migrating to Richfaces 3.3 to Richfaces 4.2 and getting following error. Our page has lot of a4j tags and couldn't quiet get which tag causing this issue. Any inputs will be appreciated

```
14:13:35,367 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/appContext].[Faces Servlet]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.component.html.HtmlAjaxSupport from [Module "deployment.app.ear.appContext.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [rt.jar:1.6.0_16]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_16]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_16]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [rt.jar:1.6.0_16]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.scanForAnnotations(BeanBuilder.java:489) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.loadBeanClass(BeanBuilder.java:453) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.bake(BeanBuilder.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:90) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:353) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:262) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_16]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<a4j:support>` has been replaced by `<a4j:ajax>`. Update all your code accordingly. The stacktrace suggests that one of the backing beans has a `HtmlAjaxSupport` property. You need to remove it.

Read the [RichFaces 3.3.x to 4.x migration guide](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-48110) to have an overview of all necessary changes which you need to make to an existing RichFaces 3.3.x webapp while migrating it to RichFaces 4.x. It's really not a matter of just replacing the JARs.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I did replace a4j:support with a4j:ajax. I guess it is related to something else. May be attributes or something.

Comment: The exception suggests that there's still one `<a4j:support>` left in some view. Or maybe you've a `HtmlAjaxSupport` property in some backing bean.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I looked at backing bean and yes, one of my backing bean using HtmlAjaxSupport. How can I migrate this to 4.2? Could you point me to any example? Another question, from stack trace, how you were able to figure this out? stacktrace not listing any of beans and not enough information except ClassNoFoundException.

Comment: Remove it. It makes no sense. Look if necessary for alternate ways to achieve the same functional requirement. As to the stacktrace, just read class/method names. Browse if necessary through the source code of those classes/methods in the IDE. The exception occurred during loading of a backing bean class which needs to be constructed for the first time during displaying of an input component value.

Comment: Great! You rock in JSF2.0 world. Thanks for your time and help on this.